# MYSQL returns empty result set?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_settings` (
  `user_ID` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  `app_ID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `user_ID` (`user_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

# With these data

INSERT INTO `user_settings` (`user_ID`, `item`, `value`, `app_ID`) VALUES
(3, 'statusTrainer_ID', '0', 0),
(3, 'enabledApp', '1', 0),
(3, 'enabled_office_ID', '1', 1),
(3, 'enabled_office_ID', '2', 1),
(4, 'statusTrainer_ID', '1', 0),
(1, 'enabledApp', '1', 0),
(1, 'salesCode_ID_add', '1', 1),
(1, 'salesCode_ID_add', '2', 1),
(1, 'salesCode_ID_add', '3', 1),
(1, 'salesCode_ID_add', '20', 1),
(1, 'salesCode_ID_process', '2', 1),
(1, 'salesCode_ID_process', '3', 1),
(1, 'salesCode_ID_process', '20', 1);
```

I would like to run this query for data filtering

```
SELECT `user_ID`
FROM (`user_settings`)
WHERE (
`item` =  'enabledApp'
 AND 
`value` IN ('1') 
)
 AND 
(
`item` =  'statusTrainer_ID'
 AND 
`value` IN ('0') 
)
```

I am expecting '3' as result but MYSQL returns an empty set. why?? thanks for answer.

## UPDATED

I solved it by subquery

```
SELECT distinct `user_ID`
FROM (`user_settings`)
WHERE user_ID IN(
SELECT `user_ID`
FROM (`user_settings`)
WHERE (
item =  'enabledApp'
 AND 
value IN (1) 
))

AND user_ID IN(SELECT `user_ID`
FROM (`user_settings`)
WHERE (
item =  'statusTrainer_ID'
 AND 
value IN (0) 
))
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3be51/1)

but it's little complicated...is there some cleaner solution????

Comment: isn't `AND` should be `OR` between two condition?

Comment: yes your first query returns: 3 3 1, second EMPTY, third EMPTY

Comment: do you really have `value` field in condition??

Comment: yes...if I run conditions separately it works but together with AND not

Answer (score 1):

You need an or:

```
SELECT `user_ID`
FROM (`user_settings`)
WHERE ( `item` =  'enabledApp'  AND  `value` IN ('1')  )  OR
      ( `item` =  'statusTrainer_ID'  AND  `value` IN ('0')  )
```

It returned the empty set because item cannot be both "enabledApp" and "statusTrainer_ID".

Oh, you are trying to get user ids that have both.  Do it this way:

```
SELECT `user_ID`
FROM `user_settings`
GROUP BY `user_ID`
HAVING max(case when `item` =  'enabledApp'  AND  `value` IN ('1') then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when  `item` =  'statusTrainer_ID'  AND  `value` IN ('0') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6065b/1)

Comment: this will not give OP what he wanted... See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebbb7/1)

Comment: I don't understand why can not be both items if they are separated by brackets and the condition statement within brackets get precedence and executed first and  together or not???.

Comment: He has clarified what he wants, so I modified my answer.  The original query is a no-brainer that it will return no rows.